# Value not being set by javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that should detect which item is selected in dropdown list then change the form, this could be hiding form fields or assigning a value to a field. The hiding/showing of fields is working as it should however the value of the field does not update and is staying blank.

```
if (document.getElementById('service16').value == '4989') {
  $('#valuediv16').show();
  $('#namediv16').hide();
  $('#qtydiv16').hide();
  $('#cbdiv16').hide();    
} else if (document.getElementById('service16').value == '4946') {
  $('#cbdiv16').hide();
  $('#valuediv16').show();
  $('#value').prop("disabled", false);
  $('#namediv16').hide();
  $('#qtydiv16').show();
  $('#esetdiv16').hide();
  document.getElementById('value').value = "11.70";
} else if (document.getElementById('service16').value == '4987') {
  $('#cbdiv16').hide();
  $('#valuediv16').show();
  $('#value').prop("disabled", false);
  $('#namediv16').hide();
  $('#qtydiv16').show();
  $('#esetdiv16').hide();
  document.getElementById('value').value = "3.80";
} else if (document.getElementById('service16').value == '4988') {
  $('#cbdiv16').hide();
  $('#valuediv16').show();
  $('#value').prop("disabled", false);
  $('#namediv16').hide();
  $('#qtydiv16').show();
  $('#esetdiv16').hide();
  document.getElementById('value').value = "9.40";
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById('value').val("9.40")

Comment: Just FYI, it'd be worth researching the DRY principle to improve your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, if you are using JQuery, you should always use it and not switch between plain javascript and JQuery.

The line

```
document.getElementById('service16').value == '4988'
```

can be written in JQuery like

```
$("#service16").val() == '4988'
```

That said, converting

```
document.getElementById('value').value = "9.40";
```

to

```
$("#value").val('9.40')
```

Are you sure you are using 'value' as an id? Have you tried using another id? It's a string, but it doesn't look like a great practise to use value as an id name.

Comment: Jquery is Javascript. To say you shouldn't switch is silly.

Comment: ProEvilz, yes of course, but imo when you choose JQuery, stick with it, even if it's only for readability / colleague consensus

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#service16 option:selected').html();
```

or

```
 $('#service16 option:selected').val();
```